# Issue with Wamp on Win7 - PHP 7.2.10

Tags: php, .net, wamp, php-7.2

I'm trying to use newest version of Wamp and I also need php7 version.

My problem is:

1. When start WAMP show me 0xc000007b error
2. Orange icon - start 2 of 3 service
3. SHow me the error on PHP path
4. When try to install 'wampapache' show me again 0xc000007b error

I have Win7 and Service Pack 1 and also all necessary Visual C++ libraries.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. WAMPServer runs all its internal scripts using PHP5.6.38 as that is what they have been tested on. **It has nothing to do with the version of PHP that will run with your Web Server**.
2. You should never put any version of PHP onto your Windows PATH. WAMPServer is to flexible as it can have any number of versions of PHP installed which you can switch to with a simple menu click. V3 comes with 3 versions of PHP installed out of the box. See [this answer for an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54107629/2310830)
3. If you are getting an `0xc000007b` error, then most likely you dont have all the required MSVC RUntime libraries installed OR you didnt when you installed WAMPServer. If you installed them AFTER you installed WAMPServer, then uninstall WAMPServer, delete the `wamp` folder, and then reinstall WAMPServer AFTER you are sure ALL the MSVC Runtimes are installed. (without them the install can fail to complete all its processes.

You can find a handy utility on the WAMPServer Backup Repo [called Checks VC++ packages installed](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) It is down nearly at the bottom of the page.

You can also find a Downloadable ZIP file containing ALL the necessary MSVC Runtimes on the bottom of that page. If the Checker reports any missing MSVC Runtimes, download that too, unzip it and run EACH of the MSVC RUntime Installs in Version order (one by one). If you see a dialog saying this version is already installed, us the REPAIR button and this will ensure it is properly installed and the correct version.