# Wamp Server 3.1.4 showing (environment variable PATH) error

Tags: server, wampserver

I am getting environment variable PATH error from wamp server.

already set the path (C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.10) in advance system settings but again getting the same error

Sorry,

There is an error.

There is Wampserver path (c:/wamp64)
into Windows PATH environnement variable: (C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.10)

It seems that a PHP installation is declared in the environment variable PATH
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.10

Wampserver does not use, modify or require the PATH environment variable.
Using a PATH on Wampserver or PHP version
is detrimental to the proper functioning of Wampserver.

Press ENTER to continue...

see the picture below:

[how to resolve wamp server (path) error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K162q.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you **have** set the windows path to contain a folder to a version of PHP. WAMPServer does not need and does not like to have the PATH set to any version of PHP whether it came with WAMPServer or was installed some other way. It is all in the message on the Command Window.

So to remove the error, remove all references to any PHP you may have anywhere on your system from your PATH environment variable, regardless of whether it came with WAMPServer or was installed some other way.

The reason of course is that with WAMPServer you can have many versions of PHP installed into WAMPServer. If you notice it comes out of the box now with more than one version of PHP ready to go.

#### The Reason

If you add ONE of those PHP versions to the PATH, then when you switch to another version of PHP your PATH would still be pointing to the old version. You will undoubtedly forget to amend the PATH, and this will just cause confusion and issues, so we prefer you not to have any version of PHP on the path at all.

#### The PHP CLI

Ok so now you have no version of PHP on your path how will you run the PHP CLI (Command Line Interface) I hear you ask :)

To do this I have a little .bat/.cmd file that I place in a folder that is already on the Windows PATH so I can run it form anywhere.

I have already written that up in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597067/how-to-run-php-from-windows-command-line-in-wampserver/16289254#16289254) to a previous question, so follow this link rather than me writing it all up in 2 places.